# How to correct for "Zero distance" error when performing Mantel Test in R?

Tags: r, statistics, zero

I have the following dataset (dat):

```
popfst       long       lat
0.9         77.416667  23.25000
0.2         -6.116667  36.70000
0.3         -77.028333 -12.04333
0.3         -86.929000  40.42400
```

I wish to perform a mantel test on the following data. For which I have written the following code in R

```
location.distance <- dist(cbind(dat$long,dat$lat))
genetic.distance <- dist(dat$popfst)
as.matrix(location.distance)[1:4,1:4]
as.matrix(genetic.distance)[1:4,1:4]
mantel.rtest(location.distance, genetic.distance, nrepet = 9999)
```

However, when I run the last line I get the following error

```
Error in if (any(distmat < tol)) warning("Zero distance(s)") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am not sure how to correct for this error. I don't see [other who have](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/mantel_test.htm) attempted this facing similar error. Any suggestions?

Comment: `mantel.rtest()` cannot handle missing values. Try to complete your `dist` objects by filling the values in the upper diagonals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of these lines in your code, since the output of dist() is matrix:
as.matrix(location.distance)[1:4,1:4]

as.matrix(genetic.distance)[1:4,1:4]

Also, there is two values in popfst column that are equal (0.3). 
So distance is 0.

Try with more decimals (0.345 is different than 0.322, so distance is greater than 0)